# how to make onRecivedERC20 function?

Tags: solidity

I would like to make a function for receiving ERC20 in contract and after receiving ERC20 token it should transfer that ERC20 to another wallet.
the flow should be if a user uses that function first it should send that ERC20 to the contract and after that contract should forward that token to another wallet. I don't know where to start from

example transaction is this:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x88d85e4b746b65708a38b8f4c5d5bc0f73ff78e28868084eed565976b46df10e

Answer (score 1):

The [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard doesn't define how to notify a receiver contract about the incoming transfer. So you'll need to use either another standard (e.g. [ERC-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777)) or build a custom notification hook.

Here's an example of such custom notification. It builds on top of the OpenZeppelin ERC-20 implementation, checks if the receiver is a contract - and if it is a contract, tries to call its `onERC20Receive()` function.

You can test it by deploying two separate contracts - `MyToken` and `SomeReceiver` - and then sending tokens from the deployer address to `SomeReceiver`. You can see that the `ReceivedTokens` event was emitted, as a result of invoking the function `onERC20Receive` when `SomeReceiver` received the tokens.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MyT") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000 * 1e18);
    }

    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal override {
        if (to.code.length > 0) {
            // token recipient is a contract, notify them
            try IERC20Receiver(to).onERC20Receive(from, amount) returns (bool success) {
                // the recipient returned a bool, TODO validate if they returned true
            } catch {
                // the notification failed (maybe they don't implement the `IERC20Receiver` interface?)
            }
        }
    }
}

interface IERC20Receiver {
    function onERC20Receive(address from, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract SomeReceiver is IERC20Receiver {
    event ReceivedTokens(address from, uint256 amount);

    function onERC20Receive(address from, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
        emit ReceivedTokens(from, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```